# $ \int \sup_{n} |X_n|\leq \sup_n\int |X_n| $

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Let be $(X_n)_n $ is a sequence of integrable random varianble almost surely converges to an integrable variable. The inequality:
$$
\int \sup_{n} |X_n|\leq \sup_n\int |X_n|
$$
Is correct ?

Answer (score 2):

**Old question that without a.s. convergence:**

No. For $f_{n}(x)=n$ for $x\in[0,1/n]$ and $f_{n}(x)=0$ for otherwise, the domain is $[0,1]$. Then $\sup f_{n}=\infty$, but $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}=1$ for each $n$.

Comment: if $(X_n)_n$ is a sequence almost surely converges to an integrable variable

Comment: But this is not stated in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_{n}(x)=1$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $f_{n}(1)=2$, then $\sup_{n}f_{n}=2$ and $f_{n}\rightarrow f$, where $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $f(1)=2$. Anyway, $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}=1$, the inequality still does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

$X_n=nI_{(0,\frac  1n]}$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure. Then LHS is $\infty$ and RHS is $1$. (Note that $X_n \to 0$ almost everywhere. Also $sup_n|X_n|=[\frac  1 x]$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1, X_2$ be as below, and $X_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 3$.  This takes care of the  extra assumption "almost surely converges to an integrable variable" since it a.s. converges to $0$.

$X_1 = 1$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $X_1 = 0$ on $(1/2,1]$.

$X_2 = 0$ on $[1,1/2]$ and $X_2 = 1$ on $(1/2,1]$.

Then: $\int |X_1| = \int |X_2| = 1/2$ so that $\sup_n \int |X_n|= 1/2$.

And $\sup_n |X_n| = 1$ on $[0,1]$, so $\int\sup_n |X_n| = 1$.

The assertion in the title then would be $1 \le 1/2$.